# Debug react JSX in vscode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

I am creating a react app, and I need to see JSX at a specific point, so I started debugging using VSCode, I have my code like this:

```
 render(): JSX.Element {
        let result =  (
            <div className="footerComponent">
                <DefaultButton className={commonStyles.defaultButton} onClick= {() => this.props.saveAllSettings()} >Save Changes</DefaultButton>
                <DefaultButton className="" onClick = {() => this.setState({ dialogOpened: true})}>Discard Changes</DefaultButton>
                { this.state.dialogOpened && this.props.discardChangesDialog }
            </div>
        )
        return result
    }
```

I set a break point on the line : `return result` and I log the value in the debugging console of vscode, but it's showing this:

```
Object {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "div", key: null, ref: null, props: Object, …}
```

How do I view the exact JSX? Basically, I want to know what the expression    `{ this.state.dialogOpened && this.props.discardChangesDialog }`   returns.

Here's what I see in the Watch window:

[image]

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
render(): JSX.Element {
debugger;
this.state.dialogOpened;
this.props.discardChangesDialog
let result =  (
    <div className="footerComponent">
        <DefaultButton className={commonStyles.defaultButton} onClick= {() => this.props.saveAllSettings()} >Save Changes</DefaultButton>
        <DefaultButton className="" onClick = {() => this.setState({ dialogOpened: true})}>Discard Changes</DefaultButton>
        { this.state.dialogOpened && this.props.discardChangesDialog }
    </div>
)
return result
}
```

Just add a debugger, and open the console.

Comment: I am already in the debugger session. as I said, I stopped at the break point, but the value of result isn't the format of JSX I am expecting in order to debug.

Comment: Okay, so add that value as a watch, hope this helps.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#watch

Comment: I already did that.. if you read my question ... the value is there, but isn't formatted as the JSX someone would expect. Please read my question again ..

Comment: `I want to know what the expression  { this.state.dialogOpened && this.props.discardChangesDialog }`, using watch you can evaluate the expression value.

In order to see how it would look like in html, you may be looking for https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring

Comment: Please check the  image in my updated question. Watch basically shows the same.

Comment: So you are putting watch on result, which is an Object and will return `Object {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "div", key: null, ref: null, props: Object, …}
`.

You need to put watch on the expression { this.state.dialogOpened && this.props.discardChangesDialog }, which you want to evaluate. So after breakpoint line 22, you can put `this.state.dialogOpened && this.props.discardChangesDialog` expression and get its value.

Comment: I tried doing that, here's what I got: https://pasteboard.co/HD8VOmn.png